# Conditional SOQL query if true or false

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am passing some params in lightning controller eg.

```
getData.setParams({
    recordId : 'xyz',
    isTrue : false
});
```

And based on **isAccount** I want different result
eg.

If isTrue = false,  i want to proceed another query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@AuraEnabled  
public static List<Investor__c> getInvestors(String recordId, Boolean isTrue){
    String soqlQuery = 'SELECT CreatedDate, Account__c, Notes__c, Comments__c, List__c, Name, LastModifiedDate, LastActivityDate, Id, Status__c, SortOrder__c, Application_Status__c WHERE';

    soqlQuery +=  isTrue ? ' Id in (Select Investor__c From Investor_Role__c Where Contact__r.AccountId=:recordId) ' : ' Deal__c =:recordId ';
    soqlQuery += ' ORDER BY Status__c DESC NULLS LAST'; 
    return database.query(soqlQuery);
}
```

Comment: Strange. How come you know all the fields, object name and their relations. Are you giving a example or ..

Comment: @RohitMourya Just giving a example. It's not strange bro